# I can't see the design page and a few other issues

Tags: android, android-studio

After I update the android studio to `version 3.0.1`, when I open my project. I have get some error and I can't see the design page but if I run the app. I have no issue.

[image]

First this error:

> Warning:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.3) is
>   ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for
>   Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1. Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be
>   used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'"
>   from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle
>   Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

The second error:

> Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.

This is my build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.hosseinyha.kardoon"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

[image]

Tanks for help

Comment: change it to `23.0.3` the red marked ..one or upgrade all dependencies to 27+

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade all your com.android.support dependencies to minimum supported versions (26.0.2+).

Also change tarcompileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, targetSdkVersion  to actual values (26+ but better to support latest - 28). Note that dependencies should have same version as buildTools and targetSdk.